# SQL Server 2008 - Crash when opening recordset

Tags: sql-server-2008, mfc

I have to do some maintenance on a software that was delivered to a customer.
This software is using database and in order to do some debugging session on my computer, I had to install SQL server 2008 R2 and the two database (MyData and MyRecord) that are used by this software.
I had some troubles doing the setting (login, mapping of the database to sa user) but I managed to go over those issues.
Now I am trying to run the software but it crashes during initialization when it tries to open a recordset.

At first I do the following to connect to the database :

```
::CoInitialize(NULL);
try   
{   
    HRESULT hr = pConnection.CreateInstance("ADODB.Connection");   
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))   
    {   
        pConnection->ConnectionTimeout = 0;   
        CString strConnect;
        strConnect.Format(_T("Data Source=MyRecord;uid=sa;pwd=sa123456;"));
        hr = pConnection->Open((_bstr_t)strConnect,"","", -1);
    }   
}
```

with pConnection defined as :

```
_ConnectionPtr pConnection;
```

After that, I am trying to read some data from the database "MyRecord" with the following code :

```
CString sqlQuery = _T("select * from 通道1设置参数表");
try
{
    pRecordset.CreateInstance(_uuidof(Recordset));
    pRecordset->Open(_bstr_t(sqlQuery ),pConnection.GetInterfacePtr(),adOpenDynamic,adLockOptimistic,adCmdText);
} 
catch(_com_error   *e)  
{  
    AfxMessageBox(e->Description());   
}
```

with pRecordSet defined as :

```
_RecordsetPtr pRecordset;
```

When the line "pRecordset->Open(...)" is run, the software crashes in the function Recordset15::Open(...) of the msado15.tli file.
In this Recordset15::Open function, the raw_Open(...) function returns DB_E_NOTABLE.
However, I am sure that the table dbo.通道1设置参数表 exists in MyRecord database.

The error is :

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

I don't know if the problem lies in the SQL server configuration or in the code.
This code works perfectly well on the customer's PC so I would go with a configuration problem.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Is the language and system locale on the customer's PC and your PC the same?

Comment: Normally yes. The customer's PC is all set in chinese so I did it too on my laptop. One thing different is the Windows Version. The customer is using Windows XP in Chinese simplified language, and I am using Windows 7 Ultimate version, all settings in "regional and language" set to Chinese simplified.

Comment: Your catch statement should be catch(_com_error & e) When you do this what error message is displayed?

Comment: TheSteve: I just changed the code following your comment. The error message is "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid Object name '通道1设置参数表'."

Comment: This means that either the table doesn't exist, or it can't parse the name. Try adding [ ] brackets around the name.  What database collation are you using? Is this the same as your customer?

Comment: TheSteve: I just found the problem ! In the ODBC connector for this database, the setting "Change the default database to" was not set to the MyRecord database. I have ticked the check-box, selected the database and now it is working correctly. Thank you TheSteve for the correction on the catch. Wouldn't have find where the problem was lying without that.

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem. I've posted the catch part as an answer.

Comment: yes, that's something needed to be known ! Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ODBC connector for this database, the setting "Change the default database to" was not set to the MyRecord database.
I have ticked the check-box, selected the database and now it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your catch statement should be catch(_com_error & e)

MFC often throws exceptions by pointers, however _com_error is a reference.